# Url does not change in display when redirecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc

action:   User/Details
View: Details

In my 'Details' view, a user can click on an actionlink that goes to
the action :User/UserBehavior  From which I again return a "Details" View.

the url shows http://User/UserBehavior

If I return redirectToAction to the Details action, I still get the "UserBehavior" action in the url.

how do I redirect and present the new url of the action? isnt that the way its supposed to be?

TO CLARIFY: WHEN YOU USE REDIRECTTOACTION, SHOULD THE URL IN THE BROWSER SHOW THE ORIGINAL ACTION OR THE ACTION YOU REDIRECTED TO?

Comment: Do you use Html.ActionLink or Ajax.ActionLink ?

Comment: Can you show the method call to RedirectToAction?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from posting back where the url is the same but internally you transfer to another view. The solution would be to redirect and hopefully there is an MVC feature for that. Use RedirectToAction("UserBehaviour"), I hope it solves your problem.